# Incorrect results with genetic algorithm image evolution

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm attempting to implement a program originally created by [Roger Alsing](http://rogeralsing.com/2008/12/07/genetic-programming-evolution-of-mona-lisa/). I've done quite a bit of research on what other people have implemented. I decided to write my program in python, and use basic triangles as the shapes. When I run the program, it does not show improvement after more generations (The triangles tend to just disappear). I'm assuming something is wrong with my mutate function. Can anyone tell me why its producing less than satisfactory results?

My code:

```
import random
import copy
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

optimal = Image.open("mona_lisa.png")
optimal = optimal.convert("RGBA")

size = width, height = optimal.size

num_shapes = 128

generations = 50000

def random_genome():
    elements = []

    for i in range(num_shapes):
        x = (random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height))
        y = (random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height))
        z = (random.randint(0, width), random.randint(0, height))
        r = random.randint(0, 255)
        g = random.randint(0, 255)
        b = random.randint(0, 255)
        alpha = random.randint(10, 255)

        elements.append([x, y, z, r, g, b, alpha])

    return elements

def render_daughter(dna):
    image = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), "white")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

    for item in dna:
        x = item[0]
        y = item[1]
        z = item[2]
        r = item[3]
        g = item[4]
        b = item[5]
        alpha = item[6]

        color = (r, g, b, alpha)

        draw.polygon([x, y, z], fill = color)

    return image

def mutate(dna):
    dna_copy = copy.deepcopy(dna)

    shape_index = random.randint(0, len(dna) - 1)
    roulette = random.random() * 2

    if roulette < 1:

        if roulette < 0.25:
            dna_copy[shape_index][3] = int(random.triangular(255, dna_copy[shape_index][3]))

        elif roulette < 0.5:
            dna_copy[shape_index][4] = int(random.triangular(255, dna_copy[shape_index][4]))

        elif roulette < 0.75:
            dna_copy[shape_index][5] = int(random.triangular(255, dna_copy[shape_index][5]))

        elif roulette < 1.0:
            dna_copy[shape_index][6] = int(0.00390625 * random.triangular(255, dna_copy[shape_index][6] * 255))

    else:

        if roulette < 1.25:
            dna_copy[shape_index][0] = (int(random.triangular(width, dna_copy[shape_index][0][0])), int(random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][0][1])))

        elif roulette < 1.5:
            dna_copy[shape_index][2] = (int(random.triangular(width, dna_copy[shape_index][3][0])), int(random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][4][1])))

        elif roulette < 1.75:
            dna_copy[shape_index][3] = (int(random.triangular(width, dna_copy[shape_index][4][0])), int(random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][5][1])))

    return dna_copy

def fitness(original, new):
    fitness = 0

    for x in range(0, width):
        for y in range(0, height):
            r1, g1, b1, a1 = original.getpixel((x, y))
            r2, g2, b2, a2 = new.getpixel((x, y))

            deltaRed = r1 - r2
            deltaGreen = g1 - g2
            deltaBlue = b1 - b2
            deltaAlpha = a1 - a2

            pixelFitness = deltaRed + deltaGreen + deltaBlue + deltaAlpha

            fitness += pixelFitness

    return fitness

def generate():
    mother = random_genome()
    best_genome = mother
    best_fitness = fitness(optimal, render_daughter(best_genome))


    for i in range(generations):
        daughter = copy.deepcopy(best_genome)
        daughter = mutate(daughter)

        daughter_fitness = fitness(optimal, render_daughter(daughter))

        if daughter_fitness < best_fitness:
            best_genome = daughter
            best_fitness = daughter_fitness

        if i % 50 == 0:
            print i

        if i % 1000 == 0:
            render_daughter(best_genome).save("iterations/output_" + str(i) + ".png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    generate()
```

The beginning image I am using:

[image: Mona Lisa]

The output image after 1,000 generations:

[image: Output 1000]

Output image after 5,000 generations:

[image: Output 5000]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking wheter the new fitness is smaller than the current fitness:

```
if daughter_fitness < best_fitness:
```

The fitness you calculate, however, can be negative:

```
deltaRed = r1 - r2
deltaGreen = g1 - g2
deltaBlue = b1 - b2
deltaAlpha = a1 - a2

pixelFitness = deltaRed + deltaGreen + deltaBlue + deltaAlpha

fitness += pixelFitness
```

The various `delta*` variables can be negative or positive; your test will favour negative deltas, increasing the whiteness of the "best" image (the higher values of `r2`, `g2` etc, the lower the fitness, and the whiter the image, until they are all at 255, 255, 255. I don't know if increasing alpha increases or decreases the transparency).

Thus, you should take the absolute value of the differences:

```
deltaRed = abs(r1 - r2)
deltaGreen = abs(g1 - g2)
deltaBlue = abs(b1 - b2)
deltaAlpha = abs(a1 - a2)
```

You could also consider the sum of the square, or square root of the sum of squares (which, basically, turns it into a least-squares fitting routine):

```
deltaRed = r1 - r2
deltaGreen = g1 - g2
deltaBlue = b1 - b2
deltaAlpha = a1 - a2

pixelFitness = math.sqrt(deltaRed**2 + deltaGreen**2 + deltaBlue**2 + deltaAlpha**2)

fitness += pixelFitness
```

Finally, I noticed your program doesn't work for me. It's in the second half of your `mutate()` function, where you assign new values to x, y or z, but use indices above 2. `random_genome()` shows that you try to access colour values instead, which are integers, and even attempt to index those.

This leads to exceptions, so I don't even know how you could get this program running. It either never ran in the first place, or you didn't properly copy-paste. I've changed that to

```
if roulette < 1.25:
    dna_copy[shape_index][0] = (int(random.triangular(
        width, dna_copy[shape_index][0][0])), int(
            random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][0][1])))
elif roulette < 1.5:
    dna_copy[shape_index][1] = (int(random.triangular(
        width, dna_copy[shape_index][1][0])), int(
            random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][1][1])))
elif roulette < 1.75:
    dna_copy[shape_index][2] = (int(random.triangular(
        width, dna_copy[shape_index][2][0])), int(
            random.triangular(height, dna_copy[shape_index][2][1])))
```

which seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sir. This clears things up a lot. Although, I've noticed that PIL isn't handling transparency very well because none of the triangles look to be semi transparent at all. Would you know why that is?

Comment: Tim, I have no idea about the transparency. My png's do show transparency, but then again, I'm using [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow), not PIL (same interface, newer code).

Comment: I was looking at that. I'll definitely have to check it out. Thank you sir.

Comment: Did you run that script? Can't get any good result even after this fixes

Comment: @AntonShkurenko I might have, but that was well over 3 years ago. I certainly can't tell you whether I had good results back then. However, "Can't get any good result" isn't very clear about the problem you're facing. I'd suggest you create a new question, with the fixed script, link to this question, point out that even with fixes you get bad results, and then show what you actually get (and what you expect).

Comment: "Can't get any good result" mean that even after a couple of hours it shows me something unrelated :) I think problem is in python 2 and python 3, anyway I'm still debugging, thanks for the answer :)